# How does one architect an entity in Core Data with a generic relationship?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-data

Say you need to architect an app with an entity that can be associated with multiple other kinds of entities. For example, you have a Picture entity that can be associated with a Meal entity, a Person entity, a Boardroom entity, a Furniture entity, etc. I can think of a number of different ways to address this problem, but -- perhaps because I'm new to Core Data -- I'm not comfortable with any of them.

The most obvious approach that comes to mind is simply creating a relationship between Picture and each entity that supports associated pictures, but this seems sloppy since pictures will have multiple "null pointers."

Another possibility is creating a superentity -- Pictureable -- or something. Every entity that supports associated pictures would be a subentity of Pictureable, and Picture itself would have a one-to-one with Pictureable. I find this approach troubling because it can't be used more than once in the context of a project (since Core Data doesn't support multiple inheritance) AND the way Core Data seems to create one table for any given root entity -- assuming a SQLite backing -- has me afeard of grouping a whole bunch of disparate subentities under the umbrella of a common superentity (I realize that thinking along these lines may smack of premature optimization, so let me know if I'm being a ninny).

A third approach is to create a composite key for Picture that consists of a "type" and a "UID." Assuming every entity in my data model has a UID, I can use this key to derive an associated managed object from a Picture instance and vice versa. This approach worries me because it sounds like it might get *slow* when fetching en masse; it also doesn't feel native enough to me.

A fourth approach -- the one I'm leaning towards for the app I'm working on -- is creating subentities for both Picture and X (where X is either Meal, Person, Boardroom, etc.) and creating a one-to-one between both of those subentities. While this approach seems like the lesser of all evils, it still seems abstruse to my untrained eye, so I wonder if there's a better way.

**Edit 1:** In the last paragraph, I meant to say I'm leaning towards creating subentities *just* for Picture, *not* both Picture and X.

Comment: "let me know if I'm being a ninny" wins it for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best variations on this theme are (not necessarily in order):

1. Use separate entities for the pictures associated with Meal, Person, Boardroom, etc. Those entities might all have the same attributes, and they might in fact all be implemented using the same class. There's nothing wrong with that, and it makes it simple to have a bidirectional relationship between each kind of entity and the entity that stores its picture.
2. Make the picture an attribute of each of the entity types rather than a separate entity. This isn't a great plan with respect to efficiency if you're storing the actual picture data in the database, but it'd be fine if you store the image as a separate file and store the path to that file in an attribute. If the images or the number of records is small, it may not really be a problem even if you do store the image data in the database.
3. Use a single entity for all the pictures but omit the inverse relationship back to the associated entity. There's a [helpful SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/764125/643383) that considers this, and the accepted answer links to the even more helpful [*Unidirectional Relationships*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW6) section of the docs. This can be a nice solution to your problem if you don't need the picture->owner relationship, but you should understand the possible risk before you go down that road.
4. Give your picture entity separate relationships for each possible kind of owner, as you described in the first option you listed. If you'll need to be able to access all the pictures as a group and you need a relationship from the picture back to its owner, and if the number of possible owner entities is relatively small, this might be your best option even if it seems sloppy to have empty attributes.

As you noticed, when you use inheritance with your entities, [all the sub-entities end up together in one big table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2321003/643383). So, your fourth option (using sub-entities for each kind of picture) is similar under the hood to your first option.

Thinking more about this question, I'm inclined toward using entity inheritance to create subentities for the pictures associated with each type of owner entity. The Picture entity would store just the data that's associated with any picture. Each subentity, like MealPicture and PersonPicture, would add a relationship to it's own particular sort of owner. This way, you get bidirectional Meal<->MealPicture and Person<->PersonPicture relationships, and because each subentity inherits all the common Picture stuff you avoid the DRY violation that was bugging you. In short, you get most of the best parts of options 1 and 3 above. Under the hood, Core Data manages the pictures as in option 4 above, but in use each of the picture subentities only exposes a single relationship.

Comment: +1 The issue with pictures is a fairly common one. I think the (1) solution with multiple customized image entities all implemented by the same NSManagedObject subclass is the best way to go. It's a little tedious and feels "wrong" for those of use trained in a strong object-oriented school but entities aren't actually classes and they behave differently in operation so it really is the best option.

Comment: @Caleb #1 is interesting. I like it, except that attributes would get duped across multiple entities. #2 is tempting, although I worry it would preclude metadata about Pictures. I had already considered #3 and was hoping to avoid it; in my specific case, the bidirectional relationship is convenient, and the CD docs discourage unidirectional relationships.

Comment: @Caleb As for the fourth option I listed, I guess you're right about it being similar under the hood to the "Pictureable" option if the number of entities that support pictures is similar to the total number entities. On the bright side, the scale problem (lack of multiple inheritance) goes away, so I'm not as averse to this solution as I am to its inverse.

Comment: @TechZen Assuming I understand what @Caleb is proposing, the violation of DRY bugs me. Perhaps his suggestion is the lesser of all evils, but it seems like CD should have a better solution for this type of problem.

Comment: See my expanded answer. The violation of DRY is really illusionary because entities aren't classes. They are description of data keys and relationships and a lot of time data is repetitive. Since Core Data seeks to closely model/simultate real-word objects, events and condition, and since those real-world things are often duplicates of each other, Core Data doesn't impose a penalty for such duplication.

Comment: @JoshuaPokotilow See the paragraph I added to the answer above. I understand your concern about DRY, and while I agree with TechZen that it's not unreasonable to have several similar but unrelated entities, I can also see wanting to avoid that. Because the picture subentities will all be the same aside from their relationship to an owner entity, inheritance seems like a good plan here. (The same probably isn't true for your owner entities because it sounds like they're each very different.

Comment: @TechZen Your point that entities != classes is excellent, and I wish I'd included that in my answer.

Comment: @Caleb That's actually what I'm doing; I misspoke when I said I was creating subentities for my owner entities. But the problem you mentioned in your original answer is still present -- that is, creating Picture subentities is scary from an under-the-hood perspective since one table will grow by 1 row for every inserted owner entity. So hypothetically, if you have 100 owner entity tables and each one has 10,000 rows, you'll wind up with a single Picture table with 1 million rows.

Comment: @JoshuaPokotilow Each row in a CD table corresponds to a managed object. If you have a million rows, it's because you have a million objects. Do you mean columns? Columns store attributes and the keys used for relationships. If you're going to use entity inheritance, you want to make sure that the subentities are very similar because the table that holds them all will contain a union of all the attributes. Picture subentities can all be very similar, but that's probably not so for your owners. As I said above, I wouldn't use inheritance there.

Comment: I think that ultimately there may not be a good solution here. I'm still thinking about refactoring my codebase to adopt the approach @Caleb described in #1, because it sounds coherent and scaleable as long as I'm willing to make some concessions (no entity inheritance, possible future repeated efforts). But as @TechZen mentioned, the likelihood of encountering enormous hardships due to a violation of DRY in this context isn't great since data schemas tend to be pretty dumb. All that having been said, I still wish there were a better way; from an OOP / RDBMS perspective, this would be trivial.

Comment: @Caleb No, I mean that if you have 1 million owner entities spread out over 100 different tables, and each of those entities has a picture, and you have just 1 table for pictures (because you use inheritance for your Picture entity) then your picture table will contain 1 million rows -- 1 row for each picture.

Comment: @Caleb let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1267/discussion-between-joshua-pokotilow-and-caleb)

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand a bit on [Caleb's excellent summation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615591/how-does-one-architect-an-entity-in-core-data-with-a-generic-relationship/6616517#6616517)...

I think it's important not to over emphasize the similarities between entities and classes. Both are abstractions that help define concrete objects but entities are very "lightweight" compared to classes. For one thing, entities don't have behaviors but just properties. For another, they exist purely to provide other concrete objects e.g. managed object context and persistent stores, a ***description*** of the data model so those concrete objects can piece everything together.

In fact, under the hood, there is no NSEntity class, there is only an NSEnitity***Description*** class. Entities are really just descriptions of how the objects in an object graph will fit together. As such, you really don't get all the overhead an inefficiency of multiplying classes when you multiply entities e.g. having a bunch of largely duplicate entities doesn't slow down the app, use more memory, interfere with method chains etc.

So, don't be afraid to use multiple seemingly redundant entities when that is the simplest solution. In Core Data, that is often the most elegant solution.

Comment: While DRY may have been the impetus for OOP, OOP isn't the only context where it makes sense. I agree, a schema that defines data keys and relationships may not be as sophisticated as a class. I also agree that modifying duplicated schemas may not be as onerous as having to ferret out inconsistencies after making changes to a codebase that violates DRY. But just because CD schemas are simpler than classes, that doesn't mean I'll whistle dixie when I'm asked to add a "lastModified" property to each of 100 different duplicate entity schemas.

Comment: The solution we're leaning towards here becomes all the more frightening when you consider entity schemas *can* have logic (behaviors) in the form of fetched properties. Not to mention, if you ever need to create a subentity for your duplicated entity, you need to tack on some coefficient to the number of subentity descriptions you'll need to generate / maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with esactly this dilemma right now. I have many different entities in my model that can be "quantified". Say I have `Apple`, `Pear`, `Farmer` for all of those Entities, I need a `AppleStack`, `PearStack`, `FarmerGroup`, which are all just object+number. I need a generic approach to this because I want to support it in a model editor I am writing, so I decided I will define a `ObjectValue` abstract entity with attributes `object`, `value`. Then I will create child entities of `ObjectValue` and will subclass them and declare a `valueEntity` constant. this way I define it only once and I can write generic code that, for example, returns the possible values of the object relationship. Moreover if I need special attributes (and I actually do for a few of those) I can still add them in the child entities.